# ajax problem - 200 OK in firebug but red message with no response body

Tags: java, ajax, firebug, cross-domain

I have small ajax problem related to cross domain as i see it.

On localmachine i created html example with some ajax:
in registration text field user types 'username', 
on every keystroke ajax sends it to 
local Tomcat, where servlet checks if that username is already used
 and sends 'taken' reponse back.

No problem on localhost at all. 
As soon as i type used 'username' servlet sends 'taken' response 
and browser displays it.

But, when i put test html page with ajax
on remote machine (some free hosting on remote network)
that sends validation request on my localhost Tomcat,
connection is made, 
in Tomcat console i see request comming, 
and in firebug in Mozzila this is Console ouput:

```
GET http://89.216.182.25:8080/Dinamicki1/UsernameServlet?username=zik 200 OK
```

...but in response tab 
there is not servlet response 'taken' 
and message in firebug is in red color

So servers communicate well, no firewall problems, response is `200 OK`
But response body is empty.

Any ideas what this red messages in firebugs are?

Thank you very much in advance.

And if anyone can recommend a some serious ajax tutorial for java
it will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use a domain-relative URL in your Ajax request:

```
/Dinamicki1/UsernameServlet?username=zik
```

Or a context-relative URL (assuming that the page is served from `/Dinamicki1`):

```
UsernameServlet?username=zik
```

With regard to "Ajax tutorial for Java", start here: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax/)

Comment: @BalusC
I guess using domain-relative URL will not help me if 
html with ajax resides on that free hosting domain
and servlet that is called from ajax 
is still on my local machine ?

So I either use this proxy solution 
or i move my servlett on same machine where html and ajax is?

Comment: You cannot fire cross-domain Ajax requests. Certainly both the ajax source and target ought to be on the same domain. A domain-relative URL is easiest way to ensure this and to spot potential bugs. A proxy servlet using `java.net.URLConnection` may indeed solve your problem. Better would be still to host all at the same machine.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use AJAX to read replies from other domains.

Your HTML must be on the same server (and same domain, port, and protocol) as the AJAX servlet.

Answer (score 2):

The 200 status reported in Firebug does not indicate the validity of the cross-domain ajax call, be it successful or not.

You might want to try using a proxy method to perform the call.

E.g. [JavaScript: Use a Web Proxy for Cross-Domain XMLHttpRequest Calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve it from [this site](http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheTomcat/article.html#tomcat_httpserver):

1. "To allow directory browsing via Apache Tomcat change the parameter "listings" in the file conf/web.xml from false to true."
2. Call your page not as `C:/Documents and Settings/.../page.html` but as `localhost:8080/your_servlet_name` (page is better named `index.html`).

This way, you will be able to make AJAX requests to `localhost:8080/your_servlet_name/something_else`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was that I had to add "www" to the url! I was using URL Rewrite, so every URL that I had (image, js, get, load, post), I needed to use full url, but it was missing "www"!

Answer (score 0):

For me, It was web api(c# .NET) request and cors was not enabled.
Added header for cors on controller and it solved the problem.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```